# TextIndex in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, mongodb-query

Given, I have a document Patient with following attributes:
name
ID
address 1
address 2
city
zip
phone

Does it make sense to TextIndex all of these fields so that I can do a text search from UI on any of these fields?

Comment: If you need the ability to find a specific word or phrase that might be in any of those fields, sure it makes sense.  Really does depend on the intent of your search. As an example, a `{$text:{search:"Austin"}}` would match people with it in their names like `Jane Austin`, `Austin Powers`, and everybody with an address in Austin.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I am thinking from performance and design perspective. Is it too expensive resource wise ( CPU and Memory), will it perform way poorer if the fields were indexed individually with Indexed?

Comment: That again depends on how you query.  If you build a text index, each field will be split by word bondaryies, each word will be stemmed, and entered into the index.  The text search will be unable to limit the search by field.  If that matches your query pattern, that may be the route to take.  However, if you need to be able to query name, address, ID, etc, separately, or sort your results by one of those fields, then individual indexes are probably better.